# Need help with hyper geometric distribution problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Consider a suitcase with 7 shirts and 3 pants. Suppose we draw 4 items
without replacement from the suitcase. Let X be the total number of shirts
we get. Compute $P(X ≤ 1)$ . This is a problem Marcel Finnan Probability Book.

Here is my solution: $$P(X \le 1)=P(X=0)+P(X+1)=\frac{\binom{7}{1}\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{10}{4}}+\frac{\binom{7}{1}\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{10}{4}}=0.06667.$$ The answer key says $0.033$ so for some reason one divides by $2$ but why?  Reason I have $P(X=0)=\frac{\binom{7}{1}\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{10}{4}}$ because only have max of $3$ pants to choose so must have at least $1$ shirt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(X=0) = 0, since it is not possible (i.e. there is 0 probability of this happening).

Aside: One could also extend the binomial coefficient to allow $\binom{3}{4} = 0$. Which again shows that $P(X=0) = \frac{\binom{7}{0}\binom{3}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}} = 0$.